# if / else is not working correctly

Tags: jquery

want to hide or display div according to scroll() checks of if/else. My script is this.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

if($(this).scrollTop() > 400){

            $("#div1").delay(100).fadeIn();
            $("#div2").delay(200).fadeIn();
            $("#div3").delay(300).fadeIn();
            $("#div4").delay(400).fadeIn();
            $("#div5").delay(500).fadeIn();
} else
    $(".task-bubble").css("display", "none");

});
```

Just have a look at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NXVTw/

It works gr8 at if but not work fine at else means

if scrolltop() > 400 then show else diplay none, but when i srcoll the scroll bar above 400 its not perfect please have look.

Any suggestion.

Comment: You don't want it to fade in or hide *every* time scroll fires.  You'll need to change it so it only fades in if hidden and hides if it's already shown.

Comment: The problem is the delay. You set them to `display:none` and after that you fade them in

Comment: but i want delay in all notifications of div.

Answer (score 1):

You are fading the elements in every single time a scroll event is fired.

Try detecting whether the result of your `if` statement changes:

```
(function() {
    var scrolled = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pos = $(this).scrollTop() > 400;
        if( pos != scrolled) {
            if( pos) {
                $("#div1").delay(100).fadeIn();
                // ...
            }
            else $(".task_bubble").css("display","none");
            scrolled = pos;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Stop all delays and animations: `$(".task_bubble").stop(1,1).css("display","none");`

Comment: but i want delay in all notifications div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop fadeIn() animation and clearing the queue using stop(true):

http://jsfiddle.net/NXVTw/2/

```
$(".task-bubble").stop(true).css("display", "none");
```

Comment: .stop(true) stuck my query. If remove this then works normally but still same problem . In JSFiddle your solution works but not in my code .stop(true) create some issue. what should i do ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know as i don't know your code...

Comment: Thanks It works i forget to put . before the stop. Sorry Great Works Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

if($(this).scrollTop()) > 400){

            $("#div1").delay(100).fadeIn();
            $("#div2").delay(200).fadeIn();
            $("#div3").delay(300).fadeIn();
            $("#div4").delay(400).fadeIn();
            $("#div5").delay(500).fadeIn();
} 
else {
    $(".task-bubble").css("display", "none");
}
});
```

Try that.

Comment: Just adding braces around a single statement won't change anything... And adding an extra close paren for no reason will break things.

Comment: It seems to me that all the braces match up, and I didn't add any parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
if($(this).scrollTop() > 400){
            $("#div1").delay(100).fadeIn();
            $("#div2").delay(200).fadeIn();
            $("#div3").delay(300).fadeIn();
            $("#div4").delay(400).fadeIn();
            $("#div5").delay(500).fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
} else
    $(".task-bubble").css("display", "none");
    
});

Use e.preventDefault() in if condition.